Grouped results with counts using two fields
I have a local sports league database (this is relevant in order for me to explain the reason for asking).  In this I have a team_matches table, and I've got in my application various ways to view the matches (by venue, by division, by date, etc.)  This works pretty well, and one most of these methods, I'm able to show an options page which has the option and the number of matches - take venue, for example:
SELECT COUNT( me.scheduled_date ) AS 'number_of_matches', venue.id, venue.url_key, venue.name
FROM team_matches me
JOIN seasons season ON season.id = me.season
JOIN venues venue ON venue.id = me.venue
WHERE ( season.id = 9 )
GROUP BY venue.id
ORDER BY venue.name ASC

If I show these results (venue name and number of matches), I get something like the below:

The problem is that one of these options is to view by team - I've not yet found a way to show this because the team could be either in the home_team or the away_team column, and I'm not sure how to show a list of teams that could be in either column, along with the counts, because the grouping surely has to be by whichever column the team appears in - if that makes sense?  Grateful in advance for any assistance!

I think some sample data and desired results would go a long way to helping us understand. Generally with these to/from problems though (airline flights, sports match ups, instant messaging, etc) you can do a UNION in a subquery to stack the to/from objects together. How you deal with the results of that UNION is dependent on your desired results though.

As the team can either be home_team or away_team, you need to consider both to count the number of matches per team.
SELECT 
    team.id, 
    team.name, 
    COUNT(*) AS number_of_matches
FROM (
    SELECT home_team AS team_id, scheduled_date
    FROM team_matches
    WHERE season = 9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT away_team AS team_id, scheduled_date
    FROM team_matches
    WHERE season = 9
) AS matches
JOIN teams AS team ON team.id = matches.team_id
GROUP BY team.id
ORDER BY team.name ASC;


Amazing, thanks so much!  I did wonder if it was a union of some sort, I just couldn't find my way to the subselect with the union.  Thank you again.
